# WPF ComboBox Binding Doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm learning WPF and I have a problem. I try to initialize the combobox data while the form is loaded, but i got nothing. Here's my code:

**xaml:**

```
<Menu x:Name="mn_MainMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="518">
    <ComboBox Name="cbm_Menu" SelectedIndex="0" Width="340">
    </ComboBox>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Demo" Width="50"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Source Code" Width="80"/>
</Menu>
```

**xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitCbxData(StaticVariable.ComboBoxData);
    }

    private void InitCbxData(string[] initStrings)
    {
        var comboBoxData = new ComboBoxData(initStrings);
        this.cbm_Menu.ItemsSource = comboBoxData.Items;
        this.cbm_Menu.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        this.cbm_Menu.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        this.cbm_Menu.SelectedValue = "1";
    }
}
```

Here's a screeshot that while i m debugging:

[image]

Update:

```
 public class ComboBoxData:ItemCollection
    {
        public ComboBoxData(params string[] initStrings) : base(initStrings) { }
        public ComboBoxData(string initString, char[] delimiters) : base(initString, delimiters) { }
    }


public class Item
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;

    public Item(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}


 public class ItemCollection : IEnumerable
{
    public Item[] Items;
    public int Ctr = 0;

    public ItemCollection(params string[] initStrings)
    {
        this.Items = new Item[initStrings.Count()];
        foreach (var s in initStrings)
        {
            this.Items[Ctr] = new Item(Ctr++, s);
        }
    }

    public ItemCollection(string initString, char[] delimiters)
    {
        string[] stringElements = initString.Split(delimiters);
        foreach (var s in stringElements)
        {
            this.Items[Ctr++] = new Item(Ctr, s);
        }
    }



    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ItemCollectionEnumerator(this);
    }
}

public class ItemCollectionEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    public int position = -1;
    public ItemCollection itemCollection;
    public ItemCollectionEnumerator(ItemCollection itemCollection)
    {
        this.itemCollection = itemCollection;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get { return itemCollection.Items[position]; }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (position < itemCollection.Items.Length - 1)
        {
            position++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: With WPF, you are not supposed to put code in your UI. Look up the MVVM pattern, WPF is meant to be programmed that way. Using MVVM is really cool, not using it will feel like you fight WPF every step of the way.

Comment: I would agree with @nvoigt. I would say that you're not learning WPF... you're trying to use WPF in a WinForms way... WPF is not WinForms. I would recommend that you stop doing what you're doing and take a look at the [Getting Started (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742119(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN before continuing. There are huge differences between WPF and WinForms and trying to write WPF without knowing how to will be a waste of your time.

Comment: Thanks for @Sheridan. As you said, i m really trying to user WPF in a WinForms way...

Comment: @Sheridan. In fact, I m not following any WPF tutorials. I just create a new project of WPF and start to coding. I'm more kind of exploring. After i can finish this tiny project, i will see the course to see what i can improve or modify (maybe totally...).

Comment: While I applaud your 'look and find out' approach, I can't stress enough that you will *not* work out WPF in that way. Almost *everything* in it is so different to other programming languages, that you will *never* find out what you need. For example, you can't write effective WPF without implementing the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), but I can see that you didn't find this out. Good luck either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void InitCbxData(string[] initStrings)
    {
        var comboBoxData = new ComboBoxData(initStrings);
        this.cbm_Menu.ItemsSource = comboBoxData.Items;
        this.cbm_Menu.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        this.cbm_Menu.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        this.cbm_Menu.SelectedValue = "1";
    }
```

I guess that this would never work. First you receive an array of strings, so, no "Name" or "Id" is available for de DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath.

The only thing it that seems to me that you have to do is

```
this.cbm_Menu.ItemsSource  = initstrings;
```

DisplayMemberPath and selectedValuePath should be used for objects that have an ID and Name as properties....(for your scenario...)

Comment: Hi sexta, thanks to answer my question. I received an array of string is to initialize the comboBoxData. It's a IEnumerable class. I will edit my post to let you understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Question Solved!

Just need to modify the public field to property in the class of Item. I don't really know why, but it worked!

Modify to :

```
    public class Item
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public Item(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Binding are only work with Properties not with field,i think this is the reason.